# change the value of a pointer from another pointer which is pointing to the first pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure as below:

```
typedef struct
{
    char        *firstname;
    char        *lastname;
    char        *address;

} STUDENT;
```

and in main program

```
int main() {

 stud = (STUDENT *) calloc(1, sizeof(STUDENT));
//I have assinged some values to stud

}
```

I have another pointer and it points to stud

```
STUDENT *abc;

abc = stud;
```

I do not free stud as abc is pointing to it.

Now my question is, in another file where I have access to abc but not stud, I would like to update stud->address based on a condition

```
if(true) {
//update stud-> address
}
```

How do I do that?

Ok, I forgot to add that the new value is freed at the end of the function:

```
 if(true) {
    //update stud-> address
      abc->address = xyz->address
    }
  free(xyz);
```

In this case abc->adress would be pointing to a null memory right? How do I update abc->address in this case;

will this work:

```
 if(true) {
        //update stud-> address
          free(abc->address);
          abc->address = strdup(xyz->address);
        }
      free(xyz);
```

Comment: Like you would normally update `stud->address` in the file where you define `stud`, just use `abc->address` instead.

Comment: if you have access to abc, then do it via abc

Comment: You should not think of pointer variables, but of pointed memory zones. The pointer variables hold their address! And you free a zone, not a pointer variable!

Comment: abc->address = pstr;  ?

Comment: Oh and by the way, you should not cast the return of functions returning `void*` like `Calloc`/`malloc`. It can hide some subtle bugs that the compiler may warn about otherwise.

Comment: I have edited by question, missed out a point sorry

Comment: Just to check, you do realise you ALSO need to allocate storage for the strings within student, yes? All you have allocated there is the space for the structure itself containing the pointers. If you've done that in some other part of the code you haven't shown, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is, in another file where I have access to `abc` but not
>   `stud`, I would like to update stud->address based on a condition
>
> ```
> if(true) {
> //update stud-> address
> }
> ```
>
> How do I do that?

Since `abc` points to the same address `stud` does, they point to the same place in memory. Any one of them will get you to the place where your data are stored.

This part:

```
 if(true) {
    //update stud-> address
      abc->address = xyz->address
    }
  free(xyz);
```

`free(xyz)` will free the memory where `abc` and `xyz` point to. But it probably will case memory leak if you allocated the `->address`. If so, it should be something like:

```
free(xyz->address);
// free any other allocated child elements
free(xyz);
```

This part:

```
 if(true) {
        //update stud-> address
          free(abc->address);
          abc->address = strdup(xyz->address);
        }
      free(xyz);
```

will also case memory leak. `strdup` do allocate memory and duplicates the string, see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html):

> The strdup() function shall return a pointer to a new string, which is
>   a duplicate of the string pointed to by s1. The returned pointer can
>   be passed to free(). A null pointer is returned if the new string
>   cannot be created.

so you also need to:

```
free(xyz->address);
// free any other allocated child elements
free(xyz);
```

If need to do a lot of referencing and dereferencing , you may want to implement some simple [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) mechanism to manage the referencing. Something as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char        *firstname;
    char        *lastname;
    char        *address;
    unsigned int ref; // reference counter
} STUDENT;

// Create new object, and initialize it. Allocation should happen only here.
STUDENT* student_new(void) {
    STUDENT* obj = (STUDENT *) calloc(1, sizeof(STUDENT));
    // add one to the reference counter +1. So far, this object has
    // been used only once.
    if( obj ) obj->ref = 1;
    return obj;
}

// Get a references to and object, never use assignment `a = b`.
STUDENT* student_get_ref(STUDENT* obj) {
    // Rather than using `abc = stud`, use this function
    // to get a reference to and object. It will
    // increase the reference counter by one and
    // simply return `obj`.
    obj->ref++;
    return obj;
}

// Destroy the object and do some clean-up, never use `free` use it instead.
void student_destroy(STUDENT* obj) {
    // when the program is done from an object,
    // we decrease -1 the reference counter by one,
    // if the reference counter hit the 0,
    // this means no one is using this object,
    // so free it.
    printf("[DBG]: ref => %d\n", obj->ref);
    if( --obj->ref == 0 ) {
        printf("[DBG]: ref => 0, Object deleted\n");
        free(obj);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    STUDENT *stud = student_new();
    STUDENT *abc;
    STUDENT *xyz;

    abc = student_get_ref(stud);
    xyz = student_get_ref(abc);

    student_destroy(stud);
    student_destroy(abc);
    student_destroy(xyz);

    return 0;
}
```

If you run it, you will see that the memory haven't been release until `stud`, `abc` and `xyz` are all done with it:

```
> example.exe
[DBG]: ref => 3
[DBG]: ref => 2
[DBG]: ref => 1
[DBG]: ref => 0, Object deleted

>
```

plus, it is a cleaner way of managing memory, less errors, all the allocation is done only in the constructors `student_new` and the freeing is done in destructors `student_destroy`. Your program no longer need to call `calloc`/`malloc`/`free`.

Answer (score 0):

If both pointers point to the same memory, it doesn't matter, which one you use for changing values in the struct, it will always be modified.

So in your other file you can simple use:

```
abc->address = something;
```

and it will be updated. When you use the other pointer `stud` it will show the changes that you did.

Comment: It should work, because you copy the memory before you free it. BTW: The title of your posting is wrong, because you are not pointing to  pointer, you just have to pointers to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

`abc` and `stud` store the same value, namely the memory address of the `malloc/calloc`.

The C syntax `abc->lastname` merely look up the memory address of `lastname` so you can read/write to it.

So you just use `abc->(<fields>)` to write and the other part of program can read the updated value.

I'm assuming you only have one thread doing the read/write, multi-threaded I/O is another beast.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to abc. Then you can just do:

```
if(true) {
   abc->address = something_new_value; //update stud-> address
}
```

As pointed by others when you dynamically allocate memory it should be directly accessible from other files also as the memory allocated by calloc() is not from the stack. 
But doing that is not necessarily a good coding practice as you may loose track of which module is accessing memory where and when.